# What goes where in Spring MVC Maven Eclipse Juno STS 3.0.0 project?

Tags: eclipse, spring, jakarta-ee, eclipse-juno

I'm creating a new Spring MVC webapp.

I used STS 3.0 Dashboard -> Spring Template Project -> Spring MVC Project (URL:http://dist.springsource.com/release/STS/help/org.springframework.templates.mvc-3.1.2.zip) to create the project.  It created a directory structure like this:

```
build/
    classes/
src/
    main/
        java/
            com/
                example/
                    web/
                        HomeController.java
        resources/
            META-INF/
            log4j.xml
        webapp/
            resources/
            WEB-INF/
                classes/
                spring/
                    appServlet/
                        servlet-context.xml
                    root-context.xml
                views/
                    home.jsp
                web.xml
    test/ ***(I'll leave out what's under test)***
target/
    classes/  ***(I'll leave out what's under classes)***
    test-classes/  ***(I'll leave out what's under testclasses)***
WebContent/
    META-INF/
        MANIFEST.MF
    WEB-INF/
        lib/
```

This does not match any directory layout I can find documentation for and it certainly looks wrong.  Like why is there a `WebContent/WEB-INF` as well as a `src/webapp/WEB-INF`? Why both a `build/` and a `target/` ?

I want to be able to build and deploy automatically from Eclipse Juno as well as from the command line using Maven, so question 1 is: how do I clean up this directory structure?

Question 2: what is the difference between `src/main/resources/` and `src/main/webapp/resources`?  How do I choose which directory to put a given static resource in?

Question 3: If I have libraries that I need to include that I cannot have Maven get, where do I put them?

Answer (score 0):

I tied it in my local and following is the folder structure:

```
.
├── pom.xml
├── src
│   ├── main
│   │   ├── java
│   │   │   └── com
│   │   │       └── test
│   │   │           └── spring
│   │   │               └── HomeController.java
│   │   ├── resources
│   │   │   ├── log4j.xml
│   │   │   └── META-INF
│   │   └── webapp
│   │       ├── resources
│   │       └── WEB-INF
│   │           ├── classes
│   │           ├── spring
│   │           │   ├── appServlet
│   │           │   │   └── servlet-context.xml
│   │           │   └── root-context.xml
│   │           ├── views
│   │           │   └── home.jsp
│   │           └── web.xml
│   └── test
│       ├── java
│       │   └── com
│       │       └── test
│       │           └── spring
│       └── resources
│           └── log4j.xml
└── target
    ├── classes
    │   ├── com
    │   │   └── test
    │   │       └── spring
    │   │           └── HomeController.class
    │   └── log4j.xml
    ├── m2e-wtp
    │   └── web-resources
    │       └── META-INF
    │           ├── MANIFEST.MF
    │           └── maven
    │               └── com.exigen
    │                   └── spring
    │                       ├── pom.properties
    │                       └── pom.xml
    └── test-classes
        ├── com
        │   └── test
        │       └── spring
        └── log4j.xml
```

(I removed the .XXX files/folder which just the metadata for eclipse)

Basically, for you question:

1. Typical `src/webapp/WEB-INF` is the maven way and `WebContent/WEB-INF` is the [WTP](http://www.eclipse.org/webtools/) way. And the maven way is suggested.
2. Also `build/` is generate by eclipse and `target/` is the maven way, you can just ignore this.
3. for **Question2**, `src/mian/resources` is the maven way which will be compiled to the `target/classes` folder. and 'src/main/webapp/resources' is used for some static resources.
4. for **Question3**, actually all the 3rd-party libraries are house in the `WEB-INF/lib` after package, so you can put your libraries into this folder, no matter using maven or not.

Comment: Your tree is missing WebContent/ entirely.  I expected to put libs in WEB-INF/lib but there is no such directory in your layout or mine.  What, for example, goes in 'WebContent/META-INF/` as opposed to `src/main/resources/META-INF`?  More to the point, where is this documented?

Comment: Yes, `WebContent/` is missed, because I used the different version. but this is the WTP way so you can ignore or just delete it and follow the maven way, this is more convenient when using maven.  about `META-INF`, you should put it with `WEB-INF`, or put it into the `src/main/resources` folder.